# How to change the rows color in Listview on specific data from Sqlite

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I am showing all data/records of student in a single list view. Now at this point I am getting all data of students. I am getting student name,student roll number , address and their status (failed/Pass) 0 for fail and 1 for pass.

I am getting it in a fine way . But now I wanted to change it instead of making two different lists for pass and fail student I just want to show those students in red who are failed. I read same type of question on Stack over flow and got the following code. But In case it is not working it is showing the whole list in red either failed or pass. please help Following is a code that I am following

```
if (view == null) {
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_list, group, false);
    }
    TextView TvName, TvRollNum, TvAddress;

    Details d = list.get(index);
    TvName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_name);
    TvRollNum = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_roll);
    TvAddress = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_address);

    if(d.getStatus().contains("0")){

        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

    }

    if(d.getStatus().contains("1")){

        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.Green);

    }





    return view;
}
```

Comment: try `if(d.getStatus().equals("fail"))`

Comment: fetch the marks from DBHelper into class having listview and check if it's less than marks required to pass, if so then set background color as red

Comment: @Apurva How can i do it in class. Yes I also wanted it to do in the class where I am setting adapter instead of custom adapter class. Can you please share me a code

Comment: where's your dbhelper?

Comment: what do you mean Do you want to share me ? Well it is made in other class where I am using cursor and retrieving data in Arraylist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I considering the case if you are making backgroud color Green Or Red based on Fail Or not.. **If you want to do this Always write else part also.**

```
if(d.getStatus().contains("0")){

  view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

 }
else
{
      view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
}
```

Comment: I am doing it too , but the point is I guess when I do this it converts all list in red , and when I put just if(d.getStatus().contains("1")){

  view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

 }
it shows empty list , it not set the listview as null if there is no data ,its mean that database has some pass students and I know it too but Why I am not getting pass students showing I have no idea

Comment: Just before this If statement in my code just put Log.v("",""+d.getStatus()); see what is this printing on log. Or Debug your code on If statement. Let me know after this.

Comment: the whole list IsAck is 0 in log

Comment: where as Through Sqlite database browser I can see the pass students what is this I can understand :(

Comment: first tell me what this value holds IsAck and getStatus(). Difference?

Comment: actually I put simplest example in question , Originally it is "IsAck"which contains 0 or 1 , I set a example to make you people understand or to clarify my problem in simple words , so now forget about the status

Comment: I think I found problem , Actually uninstalled the app and re installed it , first I put passed student data  only , and then I go to list , it was showing Pass students in list with my required green color, but as when I just put the single failed student data , and check the list it was showing the failed student data in red but the only failed student data the rest of 2 student who were passed were not getting displayed , So what would be probelm ,

Comment: Yes this is happening when I deleted the failed student the list started showing pass student in green ,

Comment: Dear, I think you have some minor mistake in your code logic. So i think you are able to do this definitely.

Comment: so where could be this mistake ?

Comment: I do not know why reason this answer had "0" as useful? I spent three days searching that answer and served me perfectly. Thank you very much!